# Clarify when and where new threads are started and stopped

Tags: java, javafx

I followed an online tutorial for building a splash screen for my JavaFX application. Here is the SplashController file:

```
package splash;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * SplashController controls the Splash.FXML file. This is the initial software display. After a 
 * designated amount of time, the MainMenu.FXML is run.  
 *
 */
public class SplashController {

@FXML 
private StackPane splashRoot;
@FXML
private ImageView splashImage;

/**
 * Called after all @FXML annotated members have been injected. Starts a new thread "SplashScreen()".
 */
@FXML void initialize() {

    new SplashScreen().start(); //Start SplashScreen thread.

}

/**
 * Inner class that extends thread. Displays the splash screen for a designated amount of time then loads
 * MainMenu.FXML, sets a new stage, and displays the main menu. Hides the splash screen.
 *
 */
class SplashScreen extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            splashImage.fitWidthProperty().bind( splashRoot.widthProperty() );  // binds the image to the rootPane width.
            Thread.sleep( 3000 ); // puts the thread (SplashScreen) to sleep in order to allow the splash to display long enough.

            Platform.runLater( new Runnable() { // Forces the main menu scene to load onto the SplashScreen thread when it is available.

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader( getClass().getResource( "../mainMenu/MainMenu.FXML" ) ); // Places MainMenu.FXML into the loader.
                    Stage stage = new Stage(); // Creates a new stage.

                    try {

                        stage.setScene( new Scene( loader.load() )  ); // Sets the scene using the root node of the loaded FXML document.

                    } catch ( IOException e ) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                    stage.setResizable(false); // Prevents user from resizing the window.
                    stage.setTitle( "Test" ); // Sets the stage title.
                    stage.show(); // Displays the stage.
                    splashRoot.getScene().getWindow().hide(); // Hides the splash screen and presumably ends the SplashScreen thread.

                }

            });

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

} 
}
```

I have tried to annotate my understanding of how the threads are working here and was hoping you could either clarify for me if the following are correct or answer the question:

1) If I was to never create any new classes that extend `thread` or create any new `Runnable()` objects, I could assume that everything in my JavaFX project is running on a single JavaFX application thread;

2) When I create the inner class `SplashScreen extends Thread` and call `start()` on it, am I creating a second thread? So I therefore have two threads - the regular JavaFX application thread and the `SplashScreen` thread;

3) When I then call `Platform.runLater( new Runnable() { .... } )` does it set that new stage, FXML, and controller in the JavaFX application thread, the SplashScreen thread, or yet a new third thread?

4) When I call `splashRoot.getScene().getWindow().hide()`, does that end the SplashScreen thread? Or is that thread continuing with the `new Runnable()` that was called by `Platform.runLater()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) If I was to never create any new classes that extend thread or
>   create any new Runnable() objects, I could assume that everything in
>   my JavaFX project is running on a single JavaFX application thread;

That is true as long you don't call anything (e.g. from other API) that does that.

> 2) When I create the inner class SplashScreen extends Thread and call
>   start() on it, am I creating a second thread? So I therefore have two
>   threads - the regular JavaFX application thread and the SplashScreen
>   thread;

Yes. Do note that `SplashScreen` uses `Platform.runLater()` when it needs to handle UI stuff.

> 3) When I then call Platform.runLater( new Runnable() { .... } ) does
>   it set that new stage, FXML, and controller in the JavaFX application
>   thread, the SplashScreen thread, or yet a new third thread?

The code calling `Platform.runLater()` is on the second thread. The `Runnable` object inside `Platform.runLater()` is an object that is put inside JavaFX Application Thread's "queue," which the thread will run after it has completed whatever it is doing or needs to do (i.e. render UI etc).

> 4) When I call splashRoot.getScene().getWindow().hide(), does that end
>   the SplashScreen thread? Or is that thread continuing with the new
>   Runnable() that was called by Platform.runLater()?

It simply closes the window that is hosting your splash screen.  <strike>The thread ends because it is the last line of code in the `Runnable` that the thread has to do</strike> . The thread ends because there is nothing else to do after placing the `Runnable` onto the JavaFX Application Thread queue.

#### Summary

1. You created a window that shows the splash screen.
2. In the controller's constructor, you created another thread.
3. In that thread, you let it (that new thread) sleep for 3000ms.
4. After it wakes up, you move back to JavaFX Application Thread, and in there you load new content and open new window, and closes the splash screen.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Great explanation - just one more clarification: Why, after waking, does it move back to the JavaFX Application Thread? Are all calls to `Platform.runLater()` queued for the application thread?

Comment: @DylanRussell The next thing you do after `Thread.sleep()` is to call `Platform.runLater()`, so the whole block there is queued on the application thread. In actual fact, that thread ends as soon it adds that `Runnable` onto the queue, regardless whether the application thread executes them or not.

Comment: thank you. So if I hypothetically removed the `Thread.sleep()`, then the `Runnable` would be queued on the `SplashScreen` thread?

Comment: @DylanRussell No. `Thread.sleep()` makes the executing thread sleep (which means the method blocks for the specified amount of duration). `Platform.runLater()` is the one queuing the `Runnable` on the application thread. This queuing is required because JavaFX *cannot* to run render stuff on other threads. Similarly, trying to do `Thread.sleep()` without creating another thread will freeze your application for that specified amount of time.